# How to scroll and scrape if a certain no.of rows only updates upon every scroll within the table element with the selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, scroll, webdriver, scrape

[Example table IMAGE which loads dynamically only 32 rows per scroll or less](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thXYw.png)

I want to scroll and scrape once after the rows fetched and again we need scroll up and again have to scrape the next loaded rows.

my code.

The below code will make scroll up and lets the rows[-1] element into the visible.

```
browser.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", rows[-1])
```

But I need the next new rows to be into the visibility. so that we can perform the scrape part.

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the URL